# Увидит ли Гугл rel=nofollow, который добавляется к ссылкам с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, google-api

На странице есть несколько ссылок. После загрузки страницы к ним добавляется атрибут `rel="nofollow"` с помощью *jQuery*.
*Google* пойдет по этим ссылкам или он таки увидит добавленный атрибут?
Я нашел несколько статей на эту тему, но очень хотелось бы ссылку на официальную доку или хотя бы на гугловский блог разработки.

Comment: Но зачем так делать? Даже если гугл поймёт, другие-то нет. Что мешает на сервере добавить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В официальных документациях этого не написано. Если бы это было достоверно известно, зачем бы авторы [этого](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) и подобных материалов проводили свои исследования?
**UPDATE**:
В исследовании, проведенном в мае 2015 года было выяснено, что гугл видит nofollow в DOM. Кроме случая, когда nofollow продублирован в HTML